# Why are flex items not wrapping?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I am attempting to make multiple rows of squares (3 per line) which have the same height.

I have written some HTML and CSS for this but the boxes all go on the same line.

Here's what I have so far:

```css
#list-wrapper {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
}
#list-wrapper div {
  width: 33.33%;
}
#list-wrapper div img {
  flex: 1;
}
```

```html
<div id="list-wrapper">
  <div>
    <img src="images/1.png" alt="image one" />
  </div>
  <div>
    <img src="images/2.png" alt="image two" />
  </div>
  <div>
    <img src="images/1.png" alt="image one" />
  </div>
  <div>
    <img src="images/2.png" alt="image two" />
  </div>
  <div>
    <img src="images/1.png" alt="image one" />
  </div>
  <div>
    <img src="images/2.png" alt="image two" />
  </div>
</div>
```

When I load the page with this all boxes appear but they are all on one line going over the parent div's 100% width.

Answer (score 96, accepted):

An initial setting of a flex container is [**`flex-wrap: nowrap`**](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#flex-wrap-property).

This means that when you create a flex container (by applying `display: flex` or `display: inline-flex` to an element) all child elements ("flex items") are confined to a single line.

To enable flex items to wrap use `flex-wrap: wrap`.

---

*Here are a few examples of how flex properties work:*

A simple flex container with various flex items containing an image:

```css
#list-wrapper {
    display: flex;
    border: 1px solid black;
}

#list-wrapper div {}

#list-wrapper div img {
    height: 150px;
    width: 150px;
}
```

```html
<div id="list-wrapper">
    <div><img src="http://i.imgur.com/60PVLis.png" alt=""></div>
    <div><img src="http://i.imgur.com/60PVLis.png" alt=""></div>
    <div><img src="http://i.imgur.com/60PVLis.png" alt=""></div>
    <div><img src="http://i.imgur.com/60PVLis.png" alt=""></div>
    <div><img src="http://i.imgur.com/60PVLis.png" alt=""></div>
    <div><img src="http://i.imgur.com/60PVLis.png" alt=""></div>
    <div><img src="http://i.imgur.com/60PVLis.png" alt=""></div>
    <div><img src="http://i.imgur.com/60PVLis.png" alt=""></div>
    <div><img src="http://i.imgur.com/60PVLis.png" alt=""></div>
    <div><img src="http://i.imgur.com/60PVLis.png" alt=""></div>
    <div><img src="http://i.imgur.com/60PVLis.png" alt=""></div>
    <div><img src="http://i.imgur.com/60PVLis.png" alt=""></div>
</div>
```

Note that only one flex property has been declared: `display: flex`. This establishes the flex container. The following behaviors are by default:

- `flex-wrap: nowrap`
- `flex-direction: row`
- `justify-content: flex-start`

To allow the items to wrap, add `flex-wrap: wrap`:

```css
#list-wrapper {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap; /* NEW */
    border: 1px solid black;
}

#list-wrapper div { }

#list-wrapper div img {
    height: 150px;
    width: 150px;
}
```

```html
<div id="list-wrapper">
    <div><img src="http://i.imgur.com/60PVLis.png" alt=""></div>
    <div><img src="http://i.imgur.com/60PVLis.png" alt=""></div>
    <div><img src="http://i.imgur.com/60PVLis.png" alt=""></div>
    <div><img src="http://i.imgur.com/60PVLis.png" alt=""></div>
    <div><img src="http://i.imgur.com/60PVLis.png" alt=""></div>
    <div><img src="http://i.imgur.com/60PVLis.png" alt=""></div>
    <div><img src="http://i.imgur.com/60PVLis.png" alt=""></div>
    <div><img src="http://i.imgur.com/60PVLis.png" alt=""></div>
    <div><img src="http://i.imgur.com/60PVLis.png" alt=""></div>
    <div><img src="http://i.imgur.com/60PVLis.png" alt=""></div>
    <div><img src="http://i.imgur.com/60PVLis.png" alt=""></div>
    <div><img src="http://i.imgur.com/60PVLis.png" alt=""></div>
</div>
```

To allow only three items per row, use the [`flex`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex) property:

```css
#list-wrapper {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    border: 1px solid black;
}

#list-wrapper div {
    margin: 10px;
    flex: 1 1 calc(33.33% - 20px); /* flex-grow, flex-shrink, 
                                      flex-basis: (width - margin) */
}

#list-wrapper div img {
    height: 150px;
    width: 150px;
}
```

```html
<div id="list-wrapper">
    <div><img src="http://i.imgur.com/60PVLis.png" alt=""></div>
    <div><img src="http://i.imgur.com/60PVLis.png" alt=""></div>
    <div><img src="http://i.imgur.com/60PVLis.png" alt=""></div>
    <div><img src="http://i.imgur.com/60PVLis.png" alt=""></div>
    <div><img src="http://i.imgur.com/60PVLis.png" alt=""></div>
    <div><img src="http://i.imgur.com/60PVLis.png" alt=""></div>
    <div><img src="http://i.imgur.com/60PVLis.png" alt=""></div>
    <div><img src="http://i.imgur.com/60PVLis.png" alt=""></div>
    <div><img src="http://i.imgur.com/60PVLis.png" alt=""></div>
    <div><img src="http://i.imgur.com/60PVLis.png" alt=""></div>
    <div><img src="http://i.imgur.com/60PVLis.png" alt=""></div>
    <div><img src="http://i.imgur.com/60PVLis.png" alt=""></div>
</div>
```

Also, all flex items have equal height by default ([`align-items: stretch`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/align-items)).

```css
#list-wrapper {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    border: 1px solid black;
}

#list-wrapper div {
    margin: 10px;
    flex: 1 1 calc(33.33% - 30px);
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    background-color: lightgreen;
    text-align: center;
}

#list-wrapper div img {
    height: 150px;
    width: 150px;
}
```

```html
<div id="list-wrapper">
    <div><img src="http://i.imgur.com/60PVLis.png" alt=""></div>
    <div><img src="http://i.imgur.com/60PVLis.png" alt=""></div>
    <div><img src="http://i.imgur.com/60PVLis.png" alt=""></div>
    <div><img src="http://i.imgur.com/60PVLis.png" alt=""></div>
    <div><img src="http://i.imgur.com/60PVLis.png" alt=""></div>
    <div><img src="http://i.imgur.com/60PVLis.png" alt=""></div>
    <div><img src="http://i.imgur.com/60PVLis.png" alt=""></div>
    <div><img src="http://i.imgur.com/60PVLis.png" alt=""></div>
    <div><img src="http://i.imgur.com/60PVLis.png" alt=""></div>
    <div><img src="http://i.imgur.com/60PVLis.png" alt=""></div>
    <div><img src="http://i.imgur.com/60PVLis.png" alt=""></div>
    <div><img src="http://i.imgur.com/60PVLis.png" alt=""></div>
</div>
```

The stretch is more noticeable if you restore `flex-wrap: nowrap` and give the container a height:

```css
#list-wrapper {
    display: flex;
    /* flex-wrap: wrap; */
    border: 1px solid black;
    height: 600px;
}

#list-wrapper div {
    margin: 10px;
    flex: 1 1 calc(33.33% - 30px);
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    background-color: lightgreen;
    text-align: center;
}

#list-wrapper div img {
    height: 150px;
    width: 150px;
}
```

```html
<div id="list-wrapper">
    <div><img src="http://i.imgur.com/60PVLis.png" alt=""></div>
    <div><img src="http://i.imgur.com/60PVLis.png" alt=""></div>
    <div><img src="http://i.imgur.com/60PVLis.png" alt=""></div>
    <div><img src="http://i.imgur.com/60PVLis.png" alt=""></div>
    <div><img src="http://i.imgur.com/60PVLis.png" alt=""></div>
    <div><img src="http://i.imgur.com/60PVLis.png" alt=""></div>
    <div><img src="http://i.imgur.com/60PVLis.png" alt=""></div>
    <div><img src="http://i.imgur.com/60PVLis.png" alt=""></div>
    <div><img src="http://i.imgur.com/60PVLis.png" alt=""></div>
    <div><img src="http://i.imgur.com/60PVLis.png" alt=""></div>
    <div><img src="http://i.imgur.com/60PVLis.png" alt=""></div>
    <div><img src="http://i.imgur.com/60PVLis.png" alt=""></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 8):

If you are using flexbox and want the content to wrap, you must specify `flex-wrap: wrap`. By default flex items don't wrap.

Your code here is doing nothing because the parent of `#list-wrapper div img` is not `display: flex`. You need to move this to `#list-wrapper div`:

```
#list-wrapper div img {
    -webkit-flex: 1;
    -ms-flex: 1;
    flex: 1;
}
```

To have the images be three-across, you should specify `flex-basis: 33.33333%`.

Change your CSS to this and it will work:

```
#list-wrapper {
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: flex;
    width: 100%;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}

#list-wrapper div {
    flex: 0 0 33.333%;
}
```

JS Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/f47prnnt/1/