# How does inline-flex container decide when text is wrapped?

Tags: html, css, sass, flexbox

I have an issue with text clipping where flex items are clipped too early even though their flex-basis is set to 0 so I would expect the flex container to stretch all items to be at least as big as the biggest item in the container. Anyway here's a fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/nxbwufLk/

How is it choosing to wrap the text? Why is it not stretching the first item.

```css
.button {
  flex: 1 1 0;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.container {
  display: inline-flex;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
<div class="button">
  Some text
</div>
<div class="button">
  Some text that is very long indeed
</div>
</div>
```

I can see that the second text is wrapped but how is that decided? There are no widths set anywhere

Comment: is this can help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33137566/why-are-flex-items-not-wrapping

Comment: If you move `flex: 1 1 0;` to the container you'll see what you had expected. While in its current position you're telling the individual blocks to stretch to themselves if that makes sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> **I can see that the second text is wrapped but how is that decided? There are no widths set anywhere**

There is a width set it's just not trivial to notice, You're using `inline-flex` which on it's own should tell you what's going on.

The width of the container will equal it's content, in this case the width of the text of both elements.

**Demo**

```css
.button {
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.container {
  display: inline-flex;
}

.test>.button {
  flex: 1 1 0;
}
```

```html
No flex properties set
<br/>
<div class="container">
  <div class="button">
    Some text
  </div>
  <div class="button">
    Some text that is very long indeed
  </div>
</div>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/> flex properties set
<br/>
<div class="container test">
  <div class="button">
    Some text
  </div>
  <div class="button">
    Some text that is very long indeed
  </div>
</div>
```

As you can see the width of the containers is the same.

---

Now regardless of what we do, the width of the container is set and won't change, so when you apply `flex: 1 1 0;` you're simply dividing that width *(evenly `flex-basis:0;`)* between the two elements and then you get the wrapping.