# How do I get this flex container to wrap in React?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, jsx

I'm trying to make a list of cards with images and a short description but I can't figure out the CSS here. This is iterating through JSON data. I can't get the flexbox to wrap to the next line. It keeps adding new articles to the first line.

```
<div className='box'>
{artData.map((data:any, key:string) => {
  return (
    <li key={key} className='article'>
    <div>
    <img  src={data.images[0]}></img>
   </div>
   <br></br>      
   {data.description}</li>);
    })}
</div>
```

```
.box {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
  list-style: none;
  align-items: stretch;
  gap:20px;
  margin: 2%;
  flex-wrap: row wrap;
}
```

Update: I was missing 'flex-wrap: wrap;' Thanks everyone

Comment: maybe try to add  flex-direction: column; on your css see if that what you want. or use grid instead of flex

Comment: I was missing 'flex-wrap: wrap;' This helped: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33137566/why-are-flex-items-not-wrapping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33137566/why-are-flex-items-not-wrapping)

Comment: good you figured it out. you accepted an answer that is not answering your question just to let you know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe the parent element is positioned absolute hence why the .box class isn't restricted?

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

```css
.box {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
  list-style: none;
  align-items: stretch;
  gap:20px;
  margin: 2%;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
```